# Copy file from remote server to local machine in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin-4

I cannot figure out how I can copy a remote server file as a CSV file on my local machine (windows). I have tried

```
\copy mytable TO 'C:/pg/mytable.csv' CSV DELIMITER ','
```

It shows the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \copy ar_gp_psap TO 'C:\WazeData\WordDocs\ReportMatrix\mytab...
        ^
SQL state: 42601
```

Comment: Not seeing the remote part as `C:/pg/mytable.csv` would be local. What happened when you tried it, in particular any error messages. Add the messages as update to your question.

Comment: Check here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49927/184905

Comment: Thanks. I have added the error message. I have read that thread and didn't understand the solution. Not sure what I am missing

Comment: please just use `COPY` without "\"  :
`COPY mytable TO 'C:/pg/mytable.csv' CSV DELIMITER ','`

Comment: `\copy` is a metacommand that can only be used in the `psql` command line client. Since you seem to be using `pgAdmin4`, use this [Export/import dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.8/import_export_data.html).

Comment: I cannot use the export/import dialog. It shows the following error

"Utility file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog"

While the COPY command gives the follwoing error

"ERROR:  relative path not allowed for COPY to file
SQL state: 42602"